# mac external-hard-disk "software update"

Tags: macos, external-hard-drive, updates

When I make a software update, the files are downloaded on my MacBook's internal hard disk.

How can I set a different hard disk as default?

I suppose the files related to the software update are compressed packages that have to be saved, opened and decompressed. I would like to use the internal HD just to update MacOS, without storing any temporary files.

Thank you!
Pietro

MacBook Pro 2009, 256 GB SSD, MacOSX 10.6.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if you can change the location Software Update stores the files while it's downloading them, but you can certainly download the updates to your external hard disk from [here](http://support.apple.com/downloads/#macosandsoftware) (or select an update in Software Update and select "Go to Apple Downloads Page..." from the "Update" menu) with your favourite web browser, then install them manually with Installer.app.